# Performing operations with a list column in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table, such as `dt <- data.table(foo=list(1:3,4:6), bar=c(2,7))`. How can I perform operations on the foo list of vectors ideally using the dt[] framework? Operations might be adding bar to foo (returning list(3:5, 11:13), or seeing the position of the bar elements in the foo vectors.

I'm specifically interested in position so that I can do a 'Mean Average Position' or MAP@n calculation. To expand on this, suppose the data.table is

```
dt2 <- data.table(predictions=list(2L, 1:3, 2:5), actual=c(3, 2, 7))
```

I want to compare the predictions column with the actual column to see if my predictions (I can make up to n of them per row) turned out to be true. If the prediction for a row was accurate, then I'd want to know the position of the accurate prediction. So for dt2, the output should be `c(NA, 2, NA)`.

Comment: For the first question, you could do ```dt[, mapply(`+`, foo, bar)]``` I guess, not sure what's the second question's bout. Maybe `dt[, mapply(match, bar, foo)]`?

Comment: @asahi you're setting yourself up for hardship - don't store it in a list to begin with, expand to a regular column of values

Comment: @DavidArenburg The second question is to see which position the bar elements are in foo. So an expected result would be c(2, NA).

Comment: So did you run the code?... This is what it gives apparently

Comment: @DavidArenburg now I did, and am getting that result. I've never used mapply before, so I will study it. Thank you.

Comment: `list` columns are far from feature-complete, see [1646](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1646), [1597](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1597), [1588](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1588), [806](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/806), [582](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/582). Probably best to avoid for now. What @eddi is getting at is `data.table(foo_idx = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), foo = 1:6, bar = c(2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7))`

Comment: For David's first one, you probably want `Map` instead of `mapply`. You can also look at `sapply` and `lapply`. I agree with eddi and Michael, though, that list columns are a nice feature but not suitable for holding the core data of your analysis.

Comment: If you want to make up to n predictions per line, what would be a good alternative to a list column?

Comment: I'm not clear on what that means. Maybe edit your question so the example covers it

Comment: @Frank I've updated the 2nd paragraph of my question. DavidArenburg's code works, but I'm curious about alternatives to a list column for such a scenario.

Comment: I think the recommendation would be what eddi and Michael said. You can get to long format like `dt2_long = dt2[, lapply(.SD, unlist), by=.(r = seq(nrow(dt2)))]`. Note that I edited your input since you were mixing integers with floats. Then `dt2_long[, match(actual[1L], predictions), by=r]`