# data.table - check if one column is in another (list) column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with a column containing lists. I want to check if another column is present in the list column as.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table("a" = 1:3, "b" = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6))
```

I tried:

```
dt[, is_a_in_b := a %in% b]
dt
#    a   b is_a_in_b
# 1: 1 1,2     FALSE
# 2: 2 3,4     FALSE
# 3: 3 5,6     FALSE
```

which does not give the correct result. The desired table would be

```
dt
#    a   b is_a_in_b
# 1: 1 1,2      TRUE
# 2: 2 3,4     FALSE
# 3: 3 5,6     FALSE
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796767/set-operation-within-a-list-column and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871281/performing-operations-with-a-list-column-in-a-data-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mapply` function with applying the function `%in%` to two vectors: `a` and `b`. In effect it takes a pair of vectors (lists) and produces for every index `ix` the result of `a[ix] %in% b[[ix]]`.

```
dt[, is_a_in_b := mapply('%in%', a, b)]

> dt
   a   b is_a_in_b
1: 1 1,2      TRUE
2: 2 3,4     FALSE
3: 3 5,6     FALSE
```

Comment: Edited to `mapply` since it drops the result to atomic, eliminating the need to `unlist`.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Another option `Vectorize(\`%in%\`)(a,b)`